# How come my react app is not rendering despite correct configuration?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to launch a single page webapp, but I'm having some issues getting firebase to behave. I used create-react-app to initially create the project.

What's essentially happening is that index.html loads but the app is not rendered. You can see here: https://pokerstudy.online/

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

import firebase from 'firebase';

ReactGA.intialize('UA-134743808-1', { standardImplementation: true });
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The console says that `ReactGA.intialize is not a function`. Does it work in development?

Comment: @Tholle you're right it's react-ga. I'm such an idiot can't believe I didn't take a look at the console, I thought I didn't configure something properly. However, how come this is breaking everything? When I console.log(ReactGA) is shows that there is indeed an initialize function, which I am properly using.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing how your build step is setup. It looks like there might be some issue with your chunk. It could be worth trying just putting it all in a single `bundle.js` as a start and see if that works.

Comment: @Tholle it's not during build since it doesn't work in development either. I've also tried moving the initialize elsewhere (componentDidMount of the App component) and that didn't work either